# Why is this rigid body passing through another?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Soooo guys,I was playing with rigid bodies,I have 3 cubes,two active one passive.Passive one is connected to the active ones(Physics>Constraints>Connect).The type of constraints in a hinge,and I tweaked around the Limits Z angle.It of course worked except for one weird thing.Now,as we all know rigidbodies aren't supposed to pass through one another(especially when collision is detected).But the third cube(active body) goes inside my first cube(passive body) before it pushes it out of the way. Wasn't the cube not supposed to enter inside the cube in the first place and just push it aside out of it's way.So,it arose following questions;
Q1) Why is it happening?
Q2)How do you redeem this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It could be because you have "disable collisions" on both empties used as hinge constraint. That "disables collisions between constrained rigid bodies"

Comment: I did enabled it on both of them.still not working.

Comment: no, I meant: your empties have that setting (disable collisions) set to on. That's why your rigid bodies are skipping collisions. I tried our file, disabling that setting to both, your cubes collide, and thus they can't move anymore.